# Why does this C code work? (It shouldn't)

Tags: c, comma-operator

I am checking a student's homework.
The assignment is to print the amount of English letters to the console.
For some reason, what he did works (7th line):

```
 int main(void)
 {
     char first = 'A';
     char last = 'Z';
     int amount = 0;

     amount = ("%d - %d", last - first + 1);
     printf("The amount of letters in the English alphabet is %d\n", amount); 
     return(0);
 }
```

After seeing it, I tried putting other things in the brackets instead of "%d - %d". No matter what I put there and how many commas were there, it'd only take what's after the last comma (which is the correct sentence).

What is actually happening there?

Comment: Err, are you the teacher... What you need is the comma operator.

Comment: Read about [the comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator).

Comment: Give that student A+. He taught you "comma operator".

Comment: I'd be intgerested why the student wrote `("%d - %d", last - first + 1);` anyway.

Comment: Well I have asked many, more experienced programmers the same question and nobody knew the answer. Why does this comma operator even exist? So useless... (-_-')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the examples of usage of [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). In case of

```
 ("%d - %d", last - first + 1);
```

the LHS operand of the comma operator (`"%d - %d"`) is evaluated, result is discarded, then RHS (`last - first + 1`) is evaluated and returned as the result. The result, is then assigned to `amount` and thus, you have the `amount` holding the result of the operation `last - first + 1`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.17, *comma operator*

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a `void` expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

FWIW, in this case, `"%d - %d"` is just another *string literal*, it does not carry any *special* meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have asked many programmers that are more experienced than me and nobody knew the answer...